# Integrate authorization(eg: facebook) after user has logged into the application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

In my application, the user would login into the application and then authorize facebook(by clicking a button in a secure area) to allow the application to get facebook posts etc. The application however always redirects the user to the login screen. I believe this has to do with the application configuring the CookiePolicyOptions with CheckConsentNeeded = true but setting it to false does not help. 
What am I missing?

**Page after user has logged in:**

```
<form asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">                         
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-facebook btn-icon-label" value="Facebook">
<span class="btn-inner--icon">
<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

**Identity/Account/ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public class ExternalLoginModel : PageModel
    {            
        public IActionResult OnPost(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
        {
          var redirectUrl = Url.Page("./ExternalLogin", pageHandler: "Callback", values: new { returnUrl });
          var authenticationProperties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
          return new ChallengeResult(provider, authenticationProperties);
        }
```

**StartUp.cs:**

```
public class Startup
  {
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
      {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;<= I believe that this could be one of the issues
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
      });
      services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLServerConnectionString")));
      services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
      {
        config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
      })
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
      .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

      services
        .AddAuthentication(
        )
        .AddCookie()
      .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
      {
        facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["FacebookAuthSettings:AppId"];
        facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["FacebookAuthSettings:AppSecret"];
        facebookOptions.SaveTokens = true;
        facebookOptions.Events.OnCreatingTicket = oAuthCreatingTicketContext =>
        {
          var authenticationTokens = oAuthCreatingTicketContext.Properties.GetTokens().ToList();
          var authenticationToken = new AuthenticationToken()
          {
            Name = "TicketCreated",
            Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
          };
          authenticationTokens.Add(authenticationToken);
          oAuthCreatingTicketContext.Properties.StoreTokens(authenticationTokens);
          return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
      }); 

      services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).
          AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
      {
        options.AllowAreas = true;
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
      });
      services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
      {
          options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
          options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
          options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
      });

      services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");    
      services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
      {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
      });
      //enforce HTTPS globally in the app. 
      services.Configure<MvcOptions>(mvcOptions =>
      {
        mvcOptions.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
      });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
          app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
          app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
      }
      else
      {
          app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
          // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
          app.UseHsts();
      }
      app.UseHttpsRedirection();
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseCookiePolicy();
      app.UseAuthentication();
      app.UseMvc();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You don't submit a value for `provider` with the form you've created. Even so, you're already logged in, so trying to login again isn't necessarily the best approach. Have a look [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4/Account/Manage/ExternalLogins.cshtml#L41) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4/Account/Manage/ExternalLogins.cshtml.cs#L131) for how the default UI does it.

Comment: @KirkLarkin, I am trying to authorize a user's facebook account(after he has logged in with my application's internal login system), so I can get his facebook access token, which I can then use to get other interesting facebook details for the user.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. The difference is that the approach you've gone for signs the user in to your application a second time, whereas the approach demonstrated in the references I gave do it all without signing the user in to your application again. This might not matter at all for your situation, which is fine too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I am always able to figure out answers immediately after I post to stackoverflow. @KirkLarkin is right, I need to specify the name="provider" in my facebook button.

```
<form asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">                         
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" name="provider" value="Facebook">
<span class="btn-inner--icon">
<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
```